# Commands with buttons - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

In my Discord bot, I made the help command with reactions. But recently I have heard about "buttons". A lot of developers suggested me using buttons instead of reactions. Does someone know how can I modify my code so that the message stays the same?
By the way, here's my current code:

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    contents = [
    discord.Embed(title='Utilities commands',description=
f'''
text 1    
''',colour=0xF00C0C),
    discord.Embed(title='Moderation commands',description=
f'''
text 2
''',colour=0xF00C0C),
    discord.Embed(title='Fun commands',description=
f'''
text 3
''',colour=0xF00C0C),
    discord.Embed(title='Coding commands',description=
f'''
text 4
''',colour=0xF00C0C),
    discord.Embed(title='Bot\'s info | ID: 856643485340139580',description=
'''
text 5
''',colour=0xF00C0C)
]
    pages = 5
    cur_page = 1
    message = await ctx.send(embed=contents[cur_page - 1])

    await message.add_reaction("◀️")
    await message.add_reaction("▶️")

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["◀️", "▶️"]

    while True:
        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "▶️" and cur_page != pages:
                cur_page += 1
                await message.edit(embed=contents[cur_page - 1])
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            elif str(reaction.emoji) == "◀️" and cur_page > 1:
                cur_page -= 1
                await message.edit(embed=contents[cur_page - 1])
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)

        except:
            break
```

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create an on_button_click listener.

The following code gives an example how to get it working

```
import discord
import settings
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        buttons = [Button(label="button 1", custom_id="1"), Button(label="button 2", custom_id="2"),
                   Button(label="button 3", custom_id="3")]

        channel = self.get_channel(settings.DISCORD_ROLEBOT_SETTINGS_CHANNEL)
        await channel.send("test", components=buttons)

    async def on_button_click(self, interaction):
        await interaction.respond(content=f"you clicked button {interaction.component.custom_id}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = MyClient()
    DiscordComponents(client)
    client.run(settings.DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this example!

Answer (score 1):

discord.py does not yet have components 'buttons' implemented, that is coming in v2.0.
They are available to beta test by signing up in the official discord server as a tester.

Alternatively there is a 3rd party library for components BUT it is not recommended at all since it has breaking features and monkey patches, most of which will stop working in future updates of discord.py.

I'd recommended holding off on buttons till the official release of 2.0 with documentation unless you feel competent enough to beta test 2.0 by yourself.

https://discord.gg/dpy is the discord server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! How can I sign up on their official Discord server? Because I'm curious to test them 

Comment: This is the server invite https://discord.gg/dpy, to get the actual tester role you have to use the `?tester` command in the *#testing* channel, a new channel will be available called *#beta-testing*. Also please read the last message sent in *#guild-news*

Comment: Thanks bro for the link!

Comment: This documentation is so good